# How to make Karma report test as failed when exception occurs?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a Karma test which looks like this:

```
it('testing if test will fail on exception', function () {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
    throw "an exception"; 
    expect(false).toBe(true);
});
```

The problem is this test returns valid, because the exception is thrown before the second test condition was checked. I need a solution that will work on all tests, so implementing try/catch is not the solution I am searching for. Is there a way to set Karma/Jasmine configs so that all tests fail on exception thrown? Any other good ideas?

Comment: When I run the test it fails due to that exception - `Failures: an exception thrown`.